# CORS with Delphi MVC Framework

Tags: http, delphi, cors, tms-web-core

I'm testing TMS WEB Core 2 and DMVC 3.2.2 (latest) on Delphi 11.2 by me test machine locally.

I've created a simple DMVC server with all default's setup through the wizard nothing fancy except added the CORS option.

I've created a TMS Web core project with all default's setup as well with a WebHttpRequest and WebMemo components.

I ran the DMVC server and can get the result beautify on the browser.

I ran the TMS Web core project to send a request to the server using

WebHttpRequest which is like this:

```
WebHttpRequest1.URL := 'http://localhost:8080/api/test';

WebHttpRequest1.Execute(
          procedure(AResponse: string; AReq: TJSXMLHttpRequest)
          begin        
             WebMemo1.Lines.Add(AResponse);
          end
      );
```

However I got this error:

```
ERROR
HTTP request error @http://localhost:8080/api/test | fMessage::HTTP request error @http://localhost:8080/api/test fHelpContext::0
at http://localhost:8000/Project1/Project1.js [263:50]
```

and the browser developer console shows:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080/api/test' from origin 'localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'localhost:8080' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

I want to send a request from the client to the server and get the respond in the WebMemo..

I've checked online to find that it's a backend-end problem, and some say its related to CORS, So How can I enable the CORS on server side using DMVC?

Comment: The error message shows two port numbers: **8080** and **8000**. Is this as expected/configured?

Comment: Yes the server runs on localhost:8080 and client runs on localhost:8000

Comment: Is there some error message / output on the browser developer console? (F12)

Comment: Yes, its:
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/test' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8080/' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Comment: for testing on your local machine, use a CORS browser extension, such as `Allow CORS` or for Mozilla use 'CORS Everywhere'.  Once you go into production, you will need to configure your web server to allow cross origin.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration prevents the client from connecting.

Both the server name and the port must match the CORS rule. To fix this, change the CORS header to a matching value.

This could be

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost
```

or

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8000
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thanks however I know this logic but where can I uses it in the code they both don't have enough documentations for that! also, server has 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' by default

Comment: @Dreamer64 I suggest to send a support inquiry to the software publisher / author.

Comment: I did but they still couldn't answer.